# creating mysql tables with variable table names

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a platform where tables can be created from a php from and named as the variable that the submitter types. The code I have here has causes a mysql syntax error. I believe it is a matter of parenthesis placement but every combination I have tryed ha been unsuccessful can anyone figure it out? I have taken out the incorrect parenthesis to make it less confusing

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
$name=$_POST['name'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());


mysql_query("CREATE TABLE '$name'(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
name VARCHAR(30),
age INT)")
or die(mysql_error());  

echo "Table Created!";

?>   <html><form method='POST'>..........</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the syntax error that you get.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test'( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), name VARCHA' at line 1

Comment: Use backticks around $name in your query text, not single quotes. The backtick is the default delimiter for object names in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks around the table name in your SQL text:

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `$name`(
```

The backticks are the default delimiter for identifiers in MySQL. (Note: it is possible to enable other delimiters, but you don't really want to go there.)

The backticks are required if the identifier is a reserved word, contains white space, etc. (The backticks can be omitted in a lot of cases, but it's not wrong to use them when they aren't required. Basically, think of the rule as "always use backticks around identifiers", and omit them when its convenient and you are sure they aren't required.)

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
$name=$_POST['name'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());


mysql_query("CREATE TABLE ".$name."(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
name VARCHAR(30),
age INT)")
or die(mysql_error());  

echo "Table Created!";
}
?>
```

I have tested it and no problems there... it creates the table with this structure.

Answer (score 0):

CHANGE TO : `mysql_query("CREATE TABLE ".$name."(`

Answer (score 0):

You don't single quote the table name. Place it in back-ticks so that it can handle even names that match reserved words or characters. Like this

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `$name`(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
name VARCHAR(30),
age INT)")
```

You could also do without back-ticks like sin other suggested answers, but this is more reliable if you don;t want to have to check the table name against a bunch of MySQL reserved words first.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you trust the input data completely, it's very important that you validate $name to
[protect against SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).