# MySql Semi-Dynamic Table Names

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo

I'm using a MySQL database to store individual tables for each 'data object', and PDO for access. The name of the table is stored in another database/table and so must be inserted into any abstracted functions in order to write to the correct table, and incidentally a specific column/row. After much frustration, and failure to read the ENTIRE docpage, I've found out that table and column names cannot be bound when using PDO prepared statements. Darn. Since then, I understand why variables cannot be used for these fields during preparation (as well as I can), now it is time for the workaround. I understand that prepared statements are now the accepted PHP standard for preventing first order SQL injection. My question:

There are too many varying answers on SO from impossible to some other answer (see links below), so I want to make sure and choose the safest method before implementation by running it by some security minded folk. Workaround with the INFORMATION_SCHEME, Global variables, or backticks?  Rook?

[MySQL Stored Functions - Dynamic/Variable Table & Column Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593078/mysql-stored-functions-dynamic-variable-table-column-names)

or

[creating mysql tables with variable table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691090/creating-mysql-tables-with-variable-table-names)

or

[Use of wildcards in mysql table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612494/use-of-wildcards-in-mysql-table-name)

NOTE: I know that dynamic table names are looked down upon as poor design, but I consider this only semi-dynamic since the table name will be stored permanently in another table field only after validating and modifying it, and then used as a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using a MySQL database to store individual tables for each 'data object', and PDO for access.

This is what you are doing wrong. So, just

## DO NOT use MySql Semi-Dynamic Table Names.

This is not a security flaw, but violation of basic database design rules.

Please, why not to learn proper ways first? Storing objects in a single table is all right. You will have not a single problem with it. Yet it will save you A LOT of headaches, much worse than this silly problem you faced now.

Comment: You're right, this is a silly problem. I wanted the table names to be based on username for easier reference and also to prevent duplication since usernames are unique. What would the proper basic design, using a website like Facebook as an example, look like? One table for all user account settings -> "Account Settings" and then look up the particular record by username. One table for all references to user photos -> "User Photos" and then look up the record by username?  I hoped for more compartmentalization based on user, but want to prevent the future propagation of these 'silly problems'.

Comment: ...This would seem like quite a bit more queries, as opposed to retrieving each user profile with just one. But if this is the way it is done, I would prefer to follow the established model.

Comment: Do not ask such a question in comments. Just ask a regular question instead. I am sorry, but your reasoning sounds too childish, like "I want 2x2 to be 5 because I like the number". Okay, you have no education to understand the basic principles of database design. But you can at least ask a question here on Stack Overflow. It is not sufficient to enlighten at once but at least you will know the right approach

Comment: Just following directions: it says "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements". You are right, "I have no education to understand the basics of database design", but I can learn. This is the post I needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870877/avoid-using-dynamic-table-names-but-how. Thank you for your help.